# razer naga, how to assign Win key as a modifier?

Tags: razer-mouse

Does anyone know to assign Windows key as a modifier key using Razer Synapse 2.0?

I want to assign Win+S (onenote snipping tool) as a shortcut on my naga, When I use "keyboard function" for one of the side button on the naga, synapse does not recognise the win+s combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) free, open-source tool. The following [button remapping](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm) works for me with OneNote (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+)<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (`#S`):

```
XButton2::#S
```

(you can also try with `XButton1`)

If `XButton1` or `XButton2` won't work for you, use your Razer key mapping to produce something exotic, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then remap this combination to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>:

```
+!^s::
    KeyWait, Ctrl
    KeyWait, Shift
    KeyWait, Alt
    Send #S
    Return
```

Remove `KeyWait` for key modifiers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (`^`), <kbd>Alt</kbd> (`!`), <kbd>Shift</kbd> (`+`), which were ***not*** involved in shortcut before `::`. In the above example, all 3 are involved – nothing to remove.